# How to set material-css with webpack config?

Tags: css, webpack, urlloader, webpack-file-loader

Sorry to bother, because it could be a local problem. But it has been bothering me for days.

Here is my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: 'dist/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel?{"presets":["es2015"]}',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    "style-loader", "css-loader?sourceMap!postcss-loader")
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=images/[hash].[ext]"
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    vue: {
        loaders: {
            css: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css"),
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css", {
            allChunks: true,
            disable: false
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        })
    ],
    devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}
```

and my main.js:

```
import './libs/materialize/js/materialize.js'
import './libs/materialize/css/materialize.css'
```

Everything is fine, but when I check out the console of Chrome, it tells me this:

```
localhost/:13 GET http://localhost:3000/dist/dist/2751ee43015f9884c3642f103b7f70c9.woff2 
localhost/:13 GET http://localhost:3000/dist/dist/ba3dcd8903e3d0af5de7792777f8ae0d.woff 
localhost/:13 GET http://localhost:3000/dist/dist/df7b648ce5356ea1ebce435b3459fd60.ttf
```

Can you guys help me for this? Big thanks.

Comment: these are the font files everything should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You must import define like this.

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
```